# The Relationship Between Generators, Relations and Group Homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $G = \left\langle g_1, \ldots , g_n \mid R_1\right\rangle$ and $H = \left\langle h_1, \ldots , h_n \mid R_2 \right\rangle$.

Suppose there's a mapping $f$ s.t. $f(g_i) = h_i$.  Can we then merely stipulate that $f$ can be extended to mapping $f'$ s.t. $f'(ab) = f'(a)f'(b)$ so that $f'$ is a homomorphism between $G$ and $H$?

If the relations are empty, this seems to be true.  But what happens if the relations $R_1$ and $R_2$ aren't empty?  Are there extra things to check or stipulate to determine whether $f'$ is a homomorphism?

Answer (score 2):

You need more conditions. It works if you have for all $a_1\ldots a_r \in R,\; f(a_1)\ldots f(a_r) = 1_H$. (Where each $a_i = g_j^{\pm 1}$ for some $j$).

For example:

$$G = \langle x,y\; \mid\; x^3,\; y^3,\; xy\rangle \cong C_3$$
$$H = \langle u,v\; \mid\; u^2,\; v^2,\; uv=vu\rangle \cong C_2 \times C_2$$

If we define $f : G \rightarrow H$ by $f(x) = u,\; f(y) = v$, then you can check $f$ isn't a homomorphism.

Comment: This post clearly illustrates how if $f(a_i) \ne 1_H$, then $f$ needn't be a homomorphism.  Is there a way to show that if $f(a_i) = 1_H$, then $f$ **must** be a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, this follows from the universal property of free groups. If you let $F = F(\{g_1, \ldots ,g_n\})$, you can extend to a homomorphism from $F$ to $H$. Now use that all words in $R$ are in the kernel of this homomorphism, so it factors through the quotient to give a well-defined homomorphism once you quotient $F$ by the normal closure of $R$. You don't need that $f(a_i) = 1_H$, but the weaker condition that $f(a_1)\ldots f(a_r) = 1_H$ (i.e., all *words* in $R$ would be in the kernel of an extension of $f$), but if $f(a_i) = 1_H$ for all $i$, you have the previous condition anyway...